# Removing duplicate from tuple in list

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a program to store information on holiday packages. I need to output the destination but I am unsure of how to print this without any duplicates occuring.

```
for n in packagelist:
            print (n[0])
```

n[0] would be where the destination is stored and i want it to output without the same destination printed twice.

Comment: You could add the things to a set as you print them, and check if they are already in the set before you print them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `n[0]` is the destination and you want to skip all of the tuples with destinations you've seen before, imperatively:

```
seen = set()
for n in packagelist:
    if n[0] not in seen:
        print (n[0])
        seen.add(n[0])
```

Sets contain all unique elements and allow for quick lookup.  Each time you print a destination, add it to the set and if it comes up again, skip it.

Alternatively you could construct a `set` of the unique destinations, which is easier to reuse and less imperative.

```
destinations = set(n[0] for n in packagelist)
```

Comment: I had to move the seen.add(n[0]) into the if statement but other than that it worked fine thanks

Comment: @Pudie12 hm weird.  It would be better for performance but should still give the same result either way.